# What's the time complexity for max heap?

Tags: python, time-complexity, heap

I'm trying to figure out the time complexity for this whole algorithm. Isit O(nlogn) or O(n)? I've been searching online and some says max heap it's O(nlogn) and some are O(n). I am trying to get the time complexity O(n).

```
def max_heapify(A, i):
    left = 2 * i + 1
    right = 2 * i + 2
    largest = i
    if left < len(A) and A[left] > A[largest]:
        largest = left
    if right < len(A) and A[right] > A[largest]:
        largest = right
    if largest != i:
        A[i], A[largest] = A[largest], A[i]
        max_heapify(A, largest)


def build_max_heap(A):
    for i in range(len(A) // 2, -1, -1):
        max_heapify(A, i)
    return A
```

Comment: There is no *complexity for max heap* (or any other data structure). What operations are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have in the question rearranges array elements such that they satisfy the heap property i.e. the value of the parent node is greater than that of the children nodes. The time complexity of the heapify operation is O(n).

Here's an extract from [Wikipedia page on Min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap#Build

> Creating a min-max heap is accomplished by an adaption of Floyd's linear-time heap construction algorithm, which proceeds in a bottom-up fashion.[10] A typical Floyd's build-heap algorithm[11] goes as follows:
>
> ```
> function FLOYD-BUILD-HEAP (h):
>     for each index i from floor(length(h)/2) down to 1 do:
>         push-down(h, i)
>     return h
> ```

Here the function `FLOYD-BUILD-HEAP` is same as your `build_max_heap` function and `push-down` is same as your `max_heapify` function.

A suggestion: the naming of your functions is a little confusing. Your `max_heapify` is not actually heapifying. It is just a part of the heapify operation. A better name could be something like `push_down` (as used in Wikipedia) or `fix_heap`.

Answer (score 0):

A heap is a data structure which supports operations including insertion and retrieval. Each operation has its own runtime complexity.

Maybe you were thinking of the runtime complexity of *heapsort* which is a sorting algorithm that uses a heap. In that case, the runtime complexity is O(n*log(n)).